# bufferedreader disconnect suddenly

Tags: bufferedreader, resteasy

I requested some data from server. So, i started asyncrontask. getGrup is get request of server.

```
     getGrup="http://192.168.56.1:8084/Server/grup/getGrupId/tarihVeSaat/"
  +grup.getGrupTarihVeSaat().getTime()+"/yoneticiId/"+grup.getYoneticiId()+";";
    new GrupOlusturRequest().execute(getGrup);
    sendUyeler="http://192.168.56.1:8084/Server/grupUyeleri/ekle";
    while(true){
        if(getGId){
            hazırlaGrupUyeleri();
            break;
        }
```

But, Sometimes br.readline() returns null, i tested someone else rest client . it is always working. try-catch didn't throw exception. I can't understand that why it returns  null variable.

```
            url = new URL(param);
            connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            connection.setReadTimeout(100);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(100);

            is=connection.getInputStream();
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));

            String satir;
            while((satir=br.readLine())!=null){
                json2=new JSONObject(satir);
            }
            status=connection.getResponseCode();
```

Serverside:
Data sends as json from server. This method is resteasy get method. This method always works on postman rest client.

```
   @GET
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Path("/getGrupId/tarihVeSaat/{tarihVeSaat}/yoneticiId/{yoneticiId}")
   public Grup getGrupId(@PathParam ("tarihVeSaat") String tarihVeSaat,@PathParam ("yoneticiId") int yoneticiId){
    Grup grup=null;
       Timestamp tarih=new Timestamp(new java.util.Date(Long.parseLong(tarihVeSaat)).getTime());
        try{
        VeritabaniIslemleri vi=new VeritabaniIslemleri();
        vi.baglan();
        grup=vi.getGrupId(TarihVeSaat.tarihZamanGoster(tarih),yoneticiId);
        vi.baglantiyiKes();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Logger.getLogger(KullaniciRestController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,e);
    }
    return grup;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDocs for [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) the only reason the method should return null is reaching the end of stream:

> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or null if the end of the stream has been reached

If a timeout or communication problem occurred you should get an exception thrown.

Is it possible the web application you're connecting to is terminating the connection without flushing its output buffer? It sounds like the issue is probably on the other end of the connection.

Comment: I didn't get an exception on both sides @MichaelPowers

Comment: You may not have gotten an exception server side but are you sure the server isn't sending truncated responses to requests? You could check this with Wireshark. Capture traffic until you get an unexpected NULL and then inspect what the server sent and make sure everything you're expecting is in the response from the server.

Comment: I understand where i made a mistake. Server sometimes can't connect to database . So, it returns null variable.Thanks anyway @MichaelPowers